# Does discord limit what information can you get using a bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I wrote a quick discord bot as a joke, that just sends a gag message to my friend every 3 or 4 days. However, I could not find my friend's account using `client.users.cache.get()` or `client.users.fetch()`. I made sure the ID I put in was correct, to no avail. I then tested it with my own account, which worked perfectly fine. The only difference was that I was in a server with this tester bot, and everyone else in that bot-dev server could receive messages from this bot. I also realized it is impossible to get other information, (friends, etc.). Is this intentional, or is this simply a bug?

Comment: You can't get friends, no. Bots essentially are just users with a couple more useful features, like being able to get users by ID and search through guilds quickly etc etc.

Comment: how do you use `client.users.fetch()`? I have tested this method with my bot and it could fetch offline users and users from different servers, so i guess there could be an error in your code.